# How to sum hours for duplicate values

Tags: sql, t-sql

i have sth like it in table in management studio

```
Name | hours
—------------
A    | 5:30
B    | 3:30
A    | 4:00
C    | 2:00
B    | 4:55
```

It is possible to add hours for A, B and C?

To result:

Hours is type: time(0)

```
Name | hoursxxx
—------------
A    | 11:30
B    | 8:25
C    | 2:00
```

I tried

```
Select 
       [Name], 
       Sum([hoursxx] ) as timeyyy 
from 
       [base].[dbo].[table]
```

But it completly dont work

Comment: you also need GROUP BY clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is painful to add hours as times.  So add hours as decimal hours:

```
select name, sum(datediff(minute, 0, hours)) / 60.0
from t
group by name;
```

You can convert this back to a time:

```
select name, dateadd(minute, sum(datediff(minute, 0, hours)), convert(time, '00:00:00'))
from t
group by name;
```

But this runs the risk of overflow, because times are limited to 24 hours.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a44b168957886191d86e0128b35909d0) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Can it be converted to more than 24 hours?

Comment: @MichaelTraveler . . . Use decimal hours.  Times don't support more than 24 hours.  I fixed the answer so the first query returns decimal hours rather than minutes.

Comment: @MichaelTraveler The range for [`time`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/time-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is _less than_ 24 hours: "00:00:00.0000000 through 23:59:59.9999999".